# CRM Dynamics - Get service uri from FaultException<OrganizationServiceFault> or IOrganizationService

Tags: c#, exception, dynamics-crm

I'd like to log an error message containing the service uri of the CRM connection in the catch block shown below. How can I get to it?

```
protected static SystemUser ReallyCreateSystemUser(IOrganizationService service, SystemUser user) {
    try {
       var systemUserId = service.Create(user);
    } catch (FaultException<OrganizationServiceFault> ex) {
        // I want to trace the service uri of the crm connection here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `ServiceUri` information is contained in the [CrmConnection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xrm.client.crmconnection.serviceuri(v=crm.7).aspx) class.

If you are building something like a console application you can create the `IOrganizationService` from a `CrmConnection`, for example:

```
var connection = new CrmConnection("CRMOnline");
var service = new OrganizationService(connection);
```

So I suggest retrieving the `ServiceUri` information at that point, for example:

```
var serviceUri = connection.ServiceUri;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I was looking for a solution using only the objects available in the catch block. I don't have the connection object available in this method and I cannot find a way to get it from the service object. I may need to do a redesign here...